# Animated Double Arrow - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please read my problem carefully. I've passed 2 days, but still, I can't figure it out.

If you go here http://thekitchen.com you'll see animated double arrow http://prntscr.com/ewcvn4

I've searched many times on the internet and copied their code, but it's not working.

Has there any way to make the similar animated double arrow?

Also, I need the animation of the site. I know about Animate CSS and WOW JS. But it can't iterate animation. So how to I can implement their animation in my site?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>SVG Animation</title>
 <style>
  body{
   background-color: green;
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta{
   position: absolute
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta {
      list-style: none;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta {
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta {
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta {
      bottom: 3rem;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 5rem;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      opacity: 0
  }
  .narrative-inner-slide-cta {
      -moz-animation: show-slide-cta .5s ease-in-out forwards .7s;
      -webkit-animation: show-slide-cta .5s ease-in-out forwards .7s;
      animation: show-slide-cta .5s ease-in-out forwards .7s
  }

  .arrowCta {
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #3a261e;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: -3px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      width: .2rem;
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
  .arrowCta--alt{
      color: #fff
  }
  .arrowCta:after,
  .arrowCta:before {
      border-right: 3px solid #3a261e;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #3a261e;
      border-left: 0 solid transparent;
      border-top: 0 solid transparent;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      height: .75rem;
      width: .75rem
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.0625em) {
      .arrowCta:after,
      .arrowCta:before {
          height: 1.125rem;
          width: 1.125rem;
          bottom: 1.125rem
      }
  }
  .arrowCta:before {
      -moz-animation: top-arrow 2s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: top-arrow 2s infinite;
      animation: top-arrow 2s infinite
  }
  .arrowCta:after {
      -moz-animation: bottom-arrow 2s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: bottom-arrow 2s infinite;
      animation: bottom-arrow 2s infinite
  }
  .arrowCta--alt:after,
  .arrowCta--alt:before {
      border-right: 3px solid #fff;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #fff
  }

  .arrowCta:after,
  .arrowCta:before{
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
  }
  .arrowCta--alt:after,
  .arrowCta--alt:before,
  .arrowCta:after,
  .arrowCta:before {
      content: ""
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="narrative-inner-slide-cta">
        <button class="arrowCta  arrowCta--alt"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some important css to be able to animate this as you want. Here it is, I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3poncovv/) - check it out...

```
<button class="arrowCta  arrowCta--alt "></button>
```

Comment: A lot's of thanks for your comment. 

Have you seen the contents (http://prntscr.com/ewe2s2) is in http://thekitchen.com/? When you scroll top to bottom, the contents fadeInUp. When you scroll to bottom to top, the contents fadeToBottom.

How to I can do it?

Comment: I think its a combination of animate.css and https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js - full page plugin. I've done similar layout with another plugin but forgot which one I used, it was long time ago. You can visit the github page and check it out. And please don't forget to mark this answer if its the correct one for you, thanks...

Comment: Yea, it may work without animate.css, i didn't had the time to test it out

Comment: Yes, my site is also created with FullPage JS, but I'm unable to figure out iterate the animation.

Comment: You need to follow instructions from FullPage.js and don't forget to check the console for any errors. I will need to check the code out, so I can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Animate CSS is working. Now animation is iterating... Below my code-

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['section0', 'section1', 'section2','section3', 'section4', 'section5', 'section6'],
        slideSelector: '.fullpagejsslide',
        sectionsColor: [' #CAC8C2', '#E4FE06', '#CAC8C2', '#8DD4D6', '#FFD4C9', '#CAC8C2', '#8DD4D6'],

        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
            $('.title-desc h2').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.title-desc p').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.goto-contact').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('#contactForm').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
        },
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            $('.title-desc h2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.title-desc p').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.goto-contact').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('#contactForm').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        },
        afterRender: function(){
            $('.title-desc h2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.title-desc p').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('.goto-contact').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            $('#contactForm').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        },
    });
```